# How to properly copy contents of one char array into another when passed to function, WITHOUT using STL?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

I want to learn how to copy the contents of one string into another, and I want to make sure my interpretation of my code is correct.  The point of this exercise is learning, so I don't want to use STL implementations -- I want to learn the algorithms myself.

I have a class called CStudent that contains a private member variable named szName.

In my Main.cpp, I have some code that reads in a line of data using getLine, and extracts a certain amount of characters using a custom substr function.

I want to set the contents of szName to the result of the substr function, but every implementation I've tried thus far just results in only a single character being copied.

Here are the pertinent parts of code:

```
class CStudent
{
public:
    void setName(char inName[]);
    void setClass(char inClass[]);
    void setGPA(float inFloat);
    char getName();
    char getClass();
    float getGPA();

private:
    char szName[20] = {};
    char szClass[10] = {};
    float fGPA{ -1.0f };
};

// Custom strcpy to enable use of setters in class
void strcpy(char inString[], char outString[], size_t outSize)
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    for (; ((inString[i] != '\0') && (i < (outSize))); i++)
    {
        outString[i] = inString[i];
    }
    outString[i] = '\0';

}

void CStudent::setName(char inName[])
{
    strcpy(inName, szName, 20);
}

// Custom substr to enable use of setters in class
void substr(char inString[], char outString[], size_t outSize, int startPos, int endPos)
{
    int inStringPos = 0, outStringPos = 0;

    //for (inStringPos = startPos, outStringPos = 0; outStringPos < outSize;)
    for (inStringPos = startPos, outStringPos = 0; inStringPos < endPos;)
    {
        outString[outStringPos++] = inString[inStringPos++];
    }
    outString[outStringPos] = '\0';

}
```

Main excerpt:

```
int main()
{
    CStudent students[25]{};
    CStudent freshmen[25]{};
    CStudent sophomores[25]{};
    CStudent juniors[25]{};
    CStudent seniors[25]{};

    // Read in data
    fstream inputFile;
    inputFile.open("input.txt");

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        char readLine[80] {};
        inputFile.getline(readLine, 80);

        char sName[20] {};
        substr(readLine, sName, 20, 0, 19);  // Only reading first character
        students[i].setName(sName);

        char sClass[10] {};
        substr(readLine, sClass, 10, 20, 29);
        students[i].setClass(sClass);
```

Where am I going wrong here?

I read the implementation of strcpy I've found in several locations and I can't seem to figure out where I went wrong.

Edit:  In the code comments I mention that it's substr that's only returning 1 char, but it's actually the setter - setName.

Comment: There is an unused `outSize` argument in substr. I think, you should check if the length of requested substring is less than the outSize.

Comment: You anyway don't want to use the [tag:STL], you probably meant not to use c++ standard library features. But it's pretty unclear which ones you want to exclude.

Comment: What makes you believe that `setName` only copies one character? How do you observe the outcome of `setName`? I can't help but notice that `getName()` is, quite unreasonably, declared to return a single `char` - could this be the source of your confusion?

Comment: In your `substr` function, why your for condition is `inStringPos < endPos`? You do not want the character at `endPos` to be copied?

Comment: Thanks for your inquiries.  I know substr works because if I step through my program, after a single iteration of substr completes, the sName variable does contain the correct information per the Visual Studio debugger.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik You were absolutely right!  *facepalm*  Thanks for catching my bug!

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Igor if you want to submit your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had incorrectly set the return type of getName to char instead of char*, which was rightfully only returning the first character of the array.  Thanks @IgorTandetnik.